# GLSurfaceView as Texture

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I've been trying to render a GLSurfaceView on the surface of a OpenGL Cube as a Texture. Is it possible? How to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to render to a framebuffer object (FBO) backed by a texture, and then render from that.

You can google for examples of FBO usage in GLES2 (the setup is a bit complicated).  One example showing it in practice is the "record GL app" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java), which is using FBOs (and a couple of other approaches) to record GLES rendering.  The last "else" clause in `doFrame()` renders to an FBO, then renders that texture twice, once on-screen, once to a video recorder.

You may want to switch from GLSurfaceView to plain SurfaceView to get more control over the rendering process.  Most of the code in Grafika uses SurfaceView or TextureView.